# WordPress Contact form7 plugin anchor tag issue

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

In word press when I specify the html anchor tag in email message body i.e

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

When we deploy it on production the email body which contains anchor tag, It deletes all message box.

Note: If we don't enter the anchor tag, Its working perfectly.

Comment: have you checked "Use HTML content type box" checkbox in mail setting?

Comment: Yeah, I already checked that

Answer (score 1):

Try below hook in function.php, HTML Template for Email

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_content_type' );
       function set_content_type( $content_type ) {
       return 'text/html';
}
```